# f-strings to symbols in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, f-string

Thank millions  for sharing and caring!

I need to create and use symbols in **dynamic way**. In fact, symbols are made based on user input and used in code so I must use f'strings to make them.
As shown below:

```
L= ['xCl', 'xNa']
for j in range(len(L)):
     locals()[L[j]] = sympy.symbols(L[j])

i = 'Na'
j  = 'Cl' 
gg = f"x{i}" * f"x{j}"
print('gg:', gg)
```

But I received the following error:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Symbol'

While I need to have:  gg = xCl * xNaCl
Could possibly let me know how can do it.

Comment: `sequence` means list (or tuple or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way my issue has gone:

```
    for j in range(len(L)):
    locals()[L[j]] = sp.symbols(L[j])
   
i = 'Na'
j = 'Cl'
g =sp.symbols(f'x{i}') * sp.symbols(f'x{j}')
type(g)
print('g:', g)
```